# Meteor call gives no results

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using Meteor 1.0
This probably is a common beginners mistake but I can't seem so find the solution.

When I ask the server to return a collection, the results are not shown. However, I console log shows me the good results.
Here is the client helper:

> ```
> Template.myProjectTips.helpers({
>   matchingProjects: function() {
>       Meteor.call('searchNearProjects', function(error, result) {
>         if (error) {
>             console.log(error.reason);
>             return;
>               } else {
>               var fields = [{}];
>               _.each(result, function(field) {
>                   fields = field;
>                   console.log('result: ' + fields.title);
>               });
>               return fields;
>           }
>       });
>
>   },
> });
> ```

Can someone help me out with it?

Comment: And how your searchNearProjects looks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your method should return a cursor, so you should remove `.fetch()` which in fact traverses the cursor to return an array. Cursor is natively supported and promoted in Meteor.

```
Meteor.methods({
  searchNearProjects: function() {
    return Project.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}, limit: 10});
  }
});
```

Also in your template code, you are replacing your array, instead you should be populating it. But since you are working with a live cursor, you don't need all of that `_.each()` traversal either. Therefore you can simply do:

```
Template.myProjectTips.helpers({
  matchingProjects: function() {
    Meteor.call('searchNearProjects', function(error, result) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error.reason);
        return;
      } else {
        return result;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

But for a very simple Mongo query like this, you should not be using a `Meteor.method`

Instead you should publishing and subscribing like this:

Server:

Meteor.publish("nearProjects", function () {
    return Project.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}, limit: 10});
  });

Client:

```
Meteor.subscribe("nearProjects");

Template.myProjectTips.helpers({
  matchingProjects: function() {
    return Project.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}, limit: 10});
  }
});
```

Or if you want to publish with some find criteria, you can pass in your arguments to your subscribe and publish functions as well.

Comment: Thanks Serkan but fields.push(field) gives an error.

Comment: My server method looks like this:

Comment: searchNearProjects: function() {
  return Project.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}, limit: 10}).fetch();
 },

Comment: @tjakko I've updated the answer based on this new information about your server method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the info I was looking for.

Comment: Great, I'm happy for you. Now you should mark the answer as accepted so that other people looking to solve similar problems can know that this one does.